# Can printf write to terminal without flushing stdout?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char a[2] = {0};
 a[0] = 't';
 printf("%s", a);

 scanf("%c", a);
 return 0;
}
```

`scanf` here will cause an automatic flush of stdout.
Running `a.out` will print `t` on the terminal before running scanf, more info: [How is printf getting flushed before scanf is executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815208/how-is-printf-getting-flushed-before-scanf-is-executed)

However, doing `a.out > out.txt` and terminating it with `^C` does not print anything inside `out.txt` yet the output still appeared on the screen without redirecting stdout with `>`.

If stdout is being flushed then why `out.txt` is still empty?
If it's not being flushed then how did `t` appear on the screen in the first example?

(I know using `\n` or a manual fflush or properly terminating the program will fix the issue, i'm just curious about this behaviour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the word **interactive**:

> The input and output dynamics of **interactive** devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3.

As soon as you redirect the standard output to a file, it is no longer *interactive*.

For example the Linux C standard library actually executes the analogue of the `isatty` library call to figure this out. If it figures out that standard output is not directed to file it will also break this relationship. It will also increase the I/O performance of programs that work as part of a command pipeline.

---

You can yourself test whether `stdout` is connected to a terminal by executing

```
#include <unistd.h>

printf("stdout is connected to a terminal: %d\n", isatty(fileno(stdout)));
```

Comment: Besides which, the standard specifies that the definition of "interactive" is implementation-defined. So, no particular behavior of flushing should ever be assumed. If it matters that `stdout` is flushed before `scanf()`, it should be flushed explicitly.