Input string is longer than the size of the char array in c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    char user[] = { [0 ... 9 ] = '\0' };  //  Initialising a char array of len 10 and default all element of char array is = '\0'
    printf("Enter your name >> ");  // stdout ->    Enter your name >> 
    scanf("%[^\n]c", user);  //  stdin -> `aldjflajdflajdflajfdlajfdlajfd` NODE: len of entr string from stdin is > then 10
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(user));  //  33
    return 0;
}


I have a char array[10] but how input string is longer than char array ?

OT: char user[] = { [0 ... 9 ] = '\0' }; == char user[10] = { 0 }; KISS...

This is why you should ALWAYS use a width specifier in your string input format.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
    char user[10] = { 0 };  // This initializes all 10 elements to zero
    printf("Enter your name >> ");
    fflush(stdout);  // (Required in some contexts)
    scanf("%9[^\n]", user);  //  stdin -> `aldjflajdflajdflajfdlajfdlajfd` reads max 9
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(user));  //  N ≤ 9
    return 0;
}

Here it does not matter how many characters the user types before pressing Enter. Only the first nine are read and stored (plus one for the terminating null character). The remaining characters remain unread in the input stream.
BTW, I generally recommend you avoid using scanf() to read user input. Get input using fgets(), then parse it into string/int/whatever.

Do we require fflush(stdout)? Doesn't scanf() flush the underlying buffer?

In C++ the input and output streams are tied, so whenever you try to cin something it first flushes cout. Not so in C. You must explicitly and intentionally flush.

C 2018 7.21.3 3:
"… When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment…". See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66815208/20017547 So it is an implementation detail.

@Fe2O3 It is not coffee I need, but good ol' sleep. :) Except that there may some truth in what I speak this time. See the above link.

@Harith You are misreading that. Fe203 is correct: line-buffering has nothing to do with flushing output before input. You must flush or it doesn’t (necessarily) happen.

(Also, it isn’t the C runtime that enforces that behavior. It is the target device.)


I have a char array[10] but how input string is longer than char array ?

You did not tell scanf() how many characters to read. You need to specify a width specifier (no pun intended) like so:
scanf("%9[^\n]", user);

Or even better, dump scanf() and use fgets():
fgets(user, sizeof user, stdin);

Note that fgets() return a null pointer to signify failure. ferror() and feof() can be used to distinguish whether fgets() failed due to an error or end-of-file was reached.
Currently, you code invokes undefined behavior by writing to out-of-bounds memory with scanf(). The call to strlen() invokes undefined behavior too, because it is poking around in memory that doesn't belong to you.

if I understood the question correctly, you're wondering why you can input more elements into an array that has 10 elements. My response to that question would be the following: you've statically allocated memory space of 10 bytes somewhere in memory, behind which there may or may not be additional free space. What you're doing next is loading more elements into that array than necessary, and sometimes you won't get any error, but other times (which will occur in 85% of cases), after running the program, you'll get the following output: "** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)", which means you've essentially overwritten memory where you didn't specify, potentially compromising some data and so on. Therefore, my advice would be to create an additional condition during input(in scanf) where you anticipate that the user of your program inputs more than 10 characters, which means that no matter how many characters you enter, it reads at most the number specified in scanf... Another solution would be dynamic memory allocation. That would be all from me from a very basic and straightforward perspective. Warm regards!
scanf("%9[^\n]", user); // Where '9' represents the specified number of characters('9' because the \0 is the tenth member in array of characters) that you allow to input. 

